# Оптимизировать инициализацию объекта

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, ссылки

Есть функция, которая принимает константную ссылку на объект

```cpp
void test(const CMyObject & obj);
```

И есть две функции: одна возвращает существующий объект

```cpp
const CMyObject & getExists();
```

а вторая конструирует новый объект

```cpp
CMyObject createNew();
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то изменить такой код

```cpp
if (objExists)
  test(getExists());
else
  test(createNew());
```

чтобы вызов функции `test()` был только один, а содержимое объекта не копировалось и не создавался пустой объект?

```cpp
CMyObject obj;  // создали пустой объект
if (objExists)
  obj = getExists(); // скопировали содержимое
else
  obj = createNew(); // создали еще один объект и скопировали содержимое
test(obj);
```

Описание функции `test()` я менять не могу

Comment: *"принимает константную ссылку на объект"* - она принимает ссылку на константный объект. Кроме того, не указано, какого должно быть время жизни объекта, передаваемого в функцию.

Comment: @user7860670 объект за пределами функции не нужен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если сохранять создаваемый объект не нужно, он чисто временный - затычка для `test()`, то, пожалуй, можно

```
test(objExists?getExists():(const CMyObject&)createNew());
```

Comment: Не работает. Такая конструкция при вызове `getExists()` вызывает конструктор копирования https://ideone.com/LqP8VG

Comment: Гм... А если так: `test(objExists?getExists():(const CMyObject&)createNew());`?

Comment: Так работает как нужно

Comment: Ну, изменил ответ :)